# IN v/s OR operator in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query on a table with huge number of entries which I am trying to improve the performance.
Which of the below SQL queries will have the best performance? 
Should I use `IN`:

```
select * from employee where id in (2,3,4,5)
```

Or should I use `OR`

```
select * from employee where id=2 or id=3 or id=4 or id=5
```

Which statement is more efficient in terms of performance?

Comment: Which one performed best when you tested them?

Comment: Not able to figure out. I am doing a POC with 2000 records and as of now executing a query directly in sqlserver. So if i get an idea on this i can change all the queries based on this and take some readings,

Comment: If you look at the query plan... `IN` gets changed to `OR` (or something unrecognisable as either). If you want to improve performance, understand the query plan. You won't be able to analyse anything based on 2,000 records (it'll just use scans for everything). Try 2,000,000

Comment: @Gophichandan Well, it depends on the schema, such as the columns in the table, data types, available indexes, cardinality statistics, etc.  So the best way to know how well something will perform is simply to test it.

Comment: I second @Nick.McDermaid suggestion about the query plan.  The plan tells the story.

Comment: In fact, [UNION](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2011/union-or-sql-server-queries/) queries should also be considered!

Comment: No.... possibly `UNION ALL` but not `UNION`. There is a big difference and you should understand it if you are performance tuning.

Comment: What options do you have to change it? Sometimes using a join or `EXISTS` can be perform better than `IN`, but if the data isn't already in a table that isn't an option.

Comment: if ids are like 1 ,2 ,3 4
then  i would USE
select * from employee where id > 1, and id <6
this will scan one only the entire data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `IN` operator is actually interoperated/Translated as `OR` operator by the SQL Server query optimizer.

For example I have Northwind database on my Sql Server 2012 instance I wrote the following two queries one using `IN` operator and the other one using `OR` operator.

### Queries

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Customers
WHERE CustomerID IN ('ALFKI','BLAUS','BONAP')
GO

SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Customers
WHERE CustomerID = 'ALFKI'
   OR CustomerID = 'BLAUS'
   OR CustomerID = 'BONAP'
GO
```

### Execution Plan:

The execution plans were exactly the same for both queries;

[image]

### Seek Predicate

Query optimiser interoperated both queries exactly the same and `IN` operator was evaluated just as `OR` operator.

[image]

### Note

To improve performance of your query you need to start looking somewhere else the issue is not with your `IN` or `OR` operator, just make sure you DO NOT use `IN` with a sub-query which may yield NULLs as it will also be evaluated as `OR` operator and when ever we have an expression `WHERE Column = NULL` it yields NULL hence you will get wrong/unexpected results.

Comment: Thank you M.Ali. Clear explanation. Yes i am looking at the other part of the query also. Thank you for the detailed explanation.